# LWJGL - How do I use a second thread to load textures

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I know that this question has been asked several times, I can't find a perfect answer anywhere.

I've been trying to use a second thread in LWJGL to load textures, while the progress bar is filling up on the display as the textures are loading in. I've written all of the code already, but when I start the second thread, it returns an exception, namely:

`Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread`

I use OGL in the main thread to render the scene. While that scene is rendering it's things, I want to load the textures.

I've tried to make the thread a `Daemon Thread`, but that returns the same error.

How do I make sure the 'texture loading'- thread is loading its textures while the main thread is updating its scene?

Or is there another way to do this?

**Some code:**

```
mainScreen = new MainScreen();
```

MainScreen.java:

```
public void update() {
    gameInitialiser.start();

    do {
        updateGameInitialiser();
        super.update();

        SceneRenderer.renderScene();
        GuiRenderer.renderGui();

        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    } while(!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE));

}

public void updateGameInitialiser() {

    if(gameInitialiser.isInterrupted()) {
        System.err.println("The Game Initialiser has been interrupted..");
    } else if(!gameInitialiser.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("The Game Initialiser has been ended!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A OpenGL context always belongs to exactly one thread, so it is not possible to use one context at the same time in multiple threads.

What you can do is to use two contexts, one for each thread. This is possible by using a so-called [shared-context](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1NjazOXJAhVCURoKHS55BLwQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengl.org%2Fwiki%2FOpenGL_Context&usg=AFQjCNGx4AYe7Lpy2Tk2dkOYpuyA6Oc9eA&sig2=xYCzRMsecGTF6KI9cMpi4g&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU), were two contexts basically have the same objects (textures, buffers, etc) while they have separated states. Then you can use one context to render the scene and the other one to upload new data.

**Additional readings:**

[Apple - OpenGL Threading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html)

[OpenGL.org - Multithreading](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading)

Comment: How do I create a shared-context? I'm new in Threads in Java, so I don't know much about it..

Comment: Have you looked into the [lwjgl mutlithreading example](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/tree/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/opengl/multithread)? They do there exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

BDL's answer about using OpenGL shared contexts is probably what you want assuming it's properly supported in LWJGL.

But an alternative is to just move the image loading to the loading thread. You could hand over the task of making the OpenGL calls that create the textures to the rendering thread.

It's the disk access and image file parsing that's usually the slow bit, if the render thread is making the OpenGL calls, it probably wouldn't get in the way of having a smooth load screen.

I find this technique useful on Android, as it lacks full support for shared opengl contexts.